# Displaying a default images when the images is null in gridview using templatefield

Tags: c#, asp.net

I trying to display an alternate images when the images is null on my gridview which i used a templatefield to display the images. but i can only type a alternate text. There is no way to insert a alternate default images. Can u guys help me?

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>
        Question Image
      </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%#     Eval("QuestionImage") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("QuestionImage")) : string.Empty %>'
                     alt="No image" height="100" width="200" />

    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option can be at row databound event, you can go to that cell (template column) and provide the image source. If that is null, then change it to default image. For example:

Event: RowDatabound

Get value of cell (template column)

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(db.imagePath))
{
imgUser.src=db.imagePath;
}
else
{
imgUser.src="/Images/default.jpg";
}
```

This is an overall idea, not exact code, so please ignore any typing or code errors. Other thing is please avoid eval.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this code for **img** tag?

```
<img src='<%# (Eval("QuestionImage") != System.DBNull.Value ? "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("QuestionImage")) : "default.jpg") %>'
height="100" width="200" />
```

Where **default.jpg** is a filename for image you want to display when the image is null.